# C# Manipulate unknown child

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

How can I modify an object without knowing the exact type.
I have problem with accessing a child's elements in a function not knowing its exact type.
This is my example. I tried explicit and implicit casting. I could not find this subject in official websites or videos on YouTube.

```
public class Animal
{
   public int age;
}
public class Deer:Animal
{
   public int horn_length;
}
public class Giraffe:Animal
{
   public int neck_length;
}
void function(Animal pet)
{
   if(pet is Deer)
   {
      pet.horn_length++;               //Error
      (Deer)pet.horn_length++;         //Error
   }
   if(pet is Giraffe)
   {
      pet.neck_length++;               //Error
      (Giraffe)pet.neck_length++;      //Error
   }
   Deer Jack = (Deer)pet;              //Error
   (pet as Deer).horn_length++;        //Error
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, if you want to do an explicit cast, you need to wrap the object inside another set of parenthesis and then access it's property: `(Deer)pet.horn_length++;` would be `((Deer)pet).horn_length++;` Here's a dotnet fiddle for an example: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TbgZeU)

Comment: Sorry. It say: Cannot convert type 'pet.Animal' to 'pet.Deer'

Comment: Works fine for me in a fiddle, updated the original: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TbgZeU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is` operator allows you to [assign the result of a type test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#type-tests) to a new local variable, like so:

```
if(pet is Deer deer)
{
    deer.horn_length++;              //no longer an error, because deer is a `Deer`
}
```

`deer` still refers to the same underlying object as `pet`, the variable is just more specifically typed.

Comment: Sorry, but it did not work. It says: An expression of type 'Animal' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'Deer'.

Comment: @user1448393 Double-check your code - are you 100% `Deer` inherits from `Animal`? See working sample:  https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRjzwDcBDMAAgDNKBeSgCgEEoBLAWzIBtKyBKegD5KAbzyVKbWozJSAzpQAiAUxVU4asIPG5J+ypvUA6ABYB7MFAD63FVADmwU4kQBuCZQC+eLx9zkGlr0lFAqAO7KWoz8/qgEAJyMRmBmljZ2js6xeNTJWjn4ifkmFla29k6mhXioAMyUGJSsnDx4uvr1UlDAfA4q/j74DU2q6iAtXNztno0NbD2UZRmVzoO1I+iUAOJsYGTU1CoT7FMzepJdC71hAMYA1hVZpoNAA===

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing an `abstract` method, say `IncrementLength` (and let `Animal` be an `abstract` class):

```
public abstract class Animal
{
   public int age;

   public void abstract void IncrementLength(int length);
}
```

And then

```
public class Deer: Animal
{
   public int horn_length;

   public override void IncrementLength(int length) 
   {
       horn_length += length;
   }
}

public class Giraffe: Animal
{
   public int neck_length;

   public override void IncrementLength(int length) 
   {
       neck_length += length;
   }
}
```

So you can put it as

```
void function(Animal pet) 
{
    pen.IncrementLength(1);
}
```